How To Enable Batch Processing for JPQL?
I have a spring boot application where I need to update my video titles based on the ids I have received.
Following is my VideoEntity.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "video_titles")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class VideoEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String videoTitle;
}

I receive a Map<Long, String> from a third party service where the key is id and value is video title. I just want to issue an update query which I have defined as follows in my repository
public interface VideoRepository extends JpaRepository<VideoEntity, Long> {

  @Modifying
  @Query("update VideoEntity v set v.videoTitle = :title where v.id = :id")
  int updateTitleById(Long id, String title);
}

Now the issue is, my Map<> can be huge that can contain thousands of entires and for performance optimization, I need to enable batch processing so that with hibernate and jpa I can do single roundtrip and update all of my entities using the JPQL provided
I have done the following uptil now but hibernate is not doing batch processing

Add configuration in .properties file and enable statistics
Retrieve Map<> from 3rd party service and call repository update function in a loop

application.properties file
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts: true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates: true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size: 50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data: true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics: true

code
  public void fetchAndUpdate(){
    Map<Long, String> data = .... // fetching from 3rd party service.
    data.forEach((key, value) -> {
      videoRepository.updateTitleById(key, value);
    });
  }

Application and Services Versions are:

Spring Boot 3.3.0
Java 21
Hibernate Core 6.5.2.Final (Dependency from spring-data-jpa)
Mysql 8.0.30


https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update
The article provides simple examples for your case.
Also note that:

When we want to use batching for inserts, we should be aware of the
primary key generation strategy. If our entities use the
GenerationType.IDENTITY identifier generator, Hibernate will silently
disable batch inserts.
Since entities in our examples use the GenerationType.SEQUENCE
identifier generator, Hibernate enables batch operations.

Start with point 6, hope this helps.

I have already checked this article. The issue is in this article it is directly modifying the fetched entity which is part of persistence context in a current transaction. Here in my example I am using custom query in the form of JPQL.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
